# Javascript: How to get the length of object but for a specific property?

Tags: javascript, object

How to get furniture children count that has property 'chair'
Is there way for example like  house.furniture.length(chair) ?
Or do I need to use .filter to filter the ones I want and than apply .length to the filtered array?

```
Object:
    house =[
     furniture: [{
          chair: {name: 'Sun'},
          chair: {name: 'vii'},
          table: {name: 'bing'},
     }]
    ]
```

Comment: An object can't hold 2 keys with the same name. The only existent 'chair' you'd have there as a result would be the one with the name "vii"

Comment: You have also answered your own question: filter, then length.

Answer (score 1):

As @boovad has said, an object cannot have two properties with the same name. Also an array cannot have non-numeric keys. You therefore need to restructure your object.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
var house = {
    furniture: {
        chairs: [{
            name: 'Sun'
        }, {
            name: 'Vii'
        }],
        tables: [{
            name: 'Bing'
        }],
    },
};
```

Then to find the number of each type of furniture:

```
house.furniture.chairs.length;  // 2
house.furniture.tables.length;  // 1
```

Comment: that would give me chairs length, but I want to get that there are 2 chairs inside furniture array

Comment: @fubar mentioned that you need to reorganise the object. One table has multiple chairs, but those chairs need to be in an array. So you can do something like this {furniture: {  'Bing' : ['sun', 'vii'] } }. If the chairs/furniture/tables have more properties - more than their name - you'll end up creating array of objects.

Comment: But, if the purpose of the code is to allocate the chairs based on the table size, you'll need to use a structure like above - keeping chairs and tables separated.

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs, that does give you that there are two chairs inside the furniture array. If this doesn't match your requirements, then please update your question and provide more information.